# Writing a Python 3 function that returns true only for a specific sequence of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and for the most part to programming in general. So apologies if this question sounds elementary:

I am simply trying to write a Python 3 function that returns true if a specific sequence of numbers is present in a list regardless if said numbers are back-to-back. For example, let's say '0,0,7' but these specific numbers might be embedded in a larger list, say [4,0,5,0,6,7].

I can write many other functions that work with lists but this problem is stumping me because the positions for the numbers are NOT fixed.

I have tried len(range) in a for loop but I get syntax errors and also can't follow the logic. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filtered list by filtering out items in the large list that are not in the sub-list first, so that you can then easily iterate through the large list in a rolling window to match the sub-list:

```
def is_in(sublist, large_list):
    subset = set(sublist)
    filtered = [i for i in large_list if i in subset]
    for i in range(len(filtered) - len(sublist) + 1):
        if filtered[i : i + len(sublist)] == sublist:
            return True
    return False
print(is_in([0, 0, 7], [4,0,5,0,6,7]))
print(is_in([0, 0, 7], [4,0,5,6,7]))
```

This outputs:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact and relatively efficient solution is to iterate through elements of `needle` and always try to locate its first occurrence in the rest of `haystack`:

```
def istherehidden(needle,haystack):
    hsp=0
    try:
        for i in needle:
            hsp+=1+haystack[hsp:].index(i)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Now `istherehidden([4,5,7],[4,0,5,0,6,7])` returns `True`, and istherehidden([5,4,7],[4,0,5,0,6,7])`returns`False`.